# Is the native AAC decoder available when using Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, pcm, aac, opencore

I'm looking for a way to decode AAC natively to PCM on Android. The decoder source code is at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/opencore/+/master/codecs_v2/audio/aac/dec, but I'm not familiar with NDK at all.

1) There's no way of doing this directly using the Android SDK, but can this be done via the NDK?

2) I would especially be interested in a simple way of accessing the decoder from SDK, with a short "bridge" through the NDK.  Is this feasible?

3) Would such a solution work all Android versions (1.5-2.2)?

4) I guess I could use http://code.google.com/p/aacplayer-android/ instead, but it looks like this implementation is fairly CPU intensive.  Does anyone have experiences with this?

Comment: regarding option 4, on my moto droid 1 it will only play the AACP stream for a few seconds then starts skipping.  On devices with a faster CPU it seems to play OK.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what the policy is here for answering really old questions but what is working well for me is using OpenSL with the NDK; it comes built in and in fact the NDK comes with an example "native-audio" that demonstrates what you need.

Comment: I've looked for this... couldn't seem to find anything about how to decode an AAC stream using the NDK. Have you got more info?

Answer (score 2):

One thing you may look into is the FFMpeg stuff, it is GPL and TuneIn radio posted their mods here: http://radiotime.com/mobile/android#/support/open-source